# Arithmetic progression finding amount of organs by sum

Tags: linear-algebra

$A_1 = 1$
$D = 3$
$A_3 = 5$

Find the $n$ ( number of organs ) that the sum of all of the organs together is $289$.

Answer: $17$

How can I do this?  Any hint ? Thanks

Comment: What organs? What is $D$? Is this some sort of progresssion? If it was arithmetic, then $A_3=A_2+D=A_1+2D=1+6=7$. If it was geometric, then $A_3=D^2 A_1=9$...

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you don’t mean that $A_2=3$, and $D=2$? In that case your progression is $A_k=2k-1$, and you want to find $n$ so that

$$1+3+5+\ldots+(2n-1)=289\;.$$

You can use the standard [formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum):

$$1+3+5+\ldots+(2n-1)=\frac{n\big(1+(2n-1)\big)}2=\frac{2n^2}2=n^2\;,$$

so you’re really just solving the equation $n^2=289$.

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain his or her objection to a fairly obvious guess at the intended problem?